# LED Display simulation Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, led

I have been very long looking for the answer to my question on the web, but I didn't found anything helpful so I decided to ask you.

Basically I want to Programm a app like how [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlZu9oADIKs) video shows. Another big deal for me is - how can I change the text size ?

For each character I should make a array of boolean to determine if the led pin should be on or off. I think this is the smartest way for displaying text in **fix** text size.

Do I have to make an array for every character in every text size I want to get this function working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you are making a Font Map for each font you wish to display on your large LED display.  Just like fonts on a regular display, Im afraid the answer is YES, you will have to make essentially a map file for every font you wish to support.

It may not have to be true booleans however, you may be able to get away with a much more compact version of the booleans by storing multiple boolean bits in a single byte, short, or int, etc...

Comment: You might also get away with rendering the letters into a bitmap on the fly.

Comment: @omz - true that, I was thinking of performing live render using OpenGL or something.  Boolean data would I THINK be much smaller than bitmaps for this type of setup.  Ultimately, there are a couple ways of thinking about it :-)

Comment: I was thinking of an _actual_ (1-bit, b/w) bitmap, which is basically a fancy 2-dimensional boolean array with the benefit that you can render text and images into it (e.g. using Quartz). I'd then use that data to render a sprite for each pixel in the bitmap...

Comment: @omz - Kinda thought thats what you meant :-) Still wondering if that would be considered memory efficient or not. I was thinking of something that has simply 2 sprites in OpenGL (on state and off state), and holding a very small boolean array (only LEDs high x LEDs wide large). Each boolean file storing a font would be essentially charWidth * charHeight * amountChars large (i.e. very very small, but may have some overhead depending on if you dont fall on an 8, 16, 0r 32 bit bound). This would be most likely be the most data efficient. Dont think you would suffer performance here either :-)

Comment: :) I meant pretty much the same: one sprite for "on", one for "off", only that I'd create the boolean arrays for each character at runtime because that's more flexible with regards to different fonts/sizes. You could also easily support the full unicode range that way (because you'd only have to render those characters that you actually need).

Comment: @omz - just curious, how would you render the FONT at runtime, without some data at rest defining that font (i.e. the boolean maps)?

Comment: Basically the same as rendering any other text in an app, using Core Graphics, e.g. `[@"A" drawInRect:...withFont:...]`, just that I'd render into a bitmap context instead of on screen...

Comment: Is it possible to get the bitmap for each character from XCode? Apple must also know how to display each character.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/iphone-images-from-character-glyphs